# What is the answer after evaluating x**y**z in Python 2.4?

Tags: python

What is the answer after evaluating `x**y**z` in Python 2.4?
x=2
y=3
z=2

I got the answer as 64 after following left-right associativity. But it seems it's wrong.

Comment: This behaviour is not version-specific. Also, 2.4 was already very far out of date when this question was asked. Also, if you simply want to know what the result of a mathematical expression is, this does not require asking; just **try it**.

Answer (score -1):

Python follows right-left associativity for '**'(here ^) exponential operator.
So x^y^z for x=2 y=3 z=2 would be 512